# Why won't my Fallout 4 settlers keep weapons equipped?

Tags: fallout-4

I play Fallout 4 on the PlayStation 4, and all I do is create settlements. I started noticing that when I equip weapons on my settlers, leave, and comeback; the weapon I give them always becomes unequipped.

It is getting really annoying, because I almost lose my settlers, when they only run up to enemies and punch them.

Is this a glitch, or just something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

NPCs not only need to be given weapons, to fight; they need to be given ammunition, too.

If an NPC runs out of ammunition for their gun, it is expected that they would equip the closest suitable weapon they could use, which would be the fists if no other melee weapon was available.

Companion NPCs are slightly different, in that they will have a unique weapon that can't be taken from them. This weapon will have unlimited ammunition.

Comment: Dw its pretty stupid how its set up. Not intuitive at all. Someone else had to help me with the whole companion weapons thing

Comment: On a sidenote: almost all weapons beside Fat Boy and Throwables are not consumed, therefore one piece of ammo is enough. The Minigun seems to be the exception, since it needs more ammo to spin up

Comment: @dube: I gave a minigun to a settler with one piece of 5 mm and when a radscorpion attacked the settlement he released a storm of bullets on it.

Comment: @Bounce cool. I didn't check myself, that piece of information was from http://fallout.wikia.com, so they are obviously wrong then :)

Comment: Does this answer need to be updated to reflect the 1 ammo thing?